# I can't to connect to a WebService in Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, permissions, plist

I have an app to connect to a WebService, with Wifi is working correct but with mobile data not working.  I testing in IOS 10.3. I think that is a problem with permissions in plist. What do I do?

Thanks

Comment: Check if your web service is available trough web browser on your mobile while on 3G data, if it is, then you will need to look into plist permissions. If not, then you have your answer you will need to check the access of the web service

Comment: Yes, the web services is available trough web browser. I tried with <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> into plist and nothing.